# Is it possible to merge 2 lookup result into an object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am quite new in mongodb.I have a collection named message which contains a field name usrId. This field can reference to a student or to an admin. so I join 3 tables of message and student and chatAdmin to find out this message is sent from whom.

But the thing is,I do not want 2 seperate object in the result fields.I just want to have one user object containing student or admin .because the message is only from one of them.

message collection :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c73d1aec058ed1b1ce0acb4"),
"msg" : "test",
"usrId" : ObjectId("5c63f0f1dcebbc69fba10db5"),
"chId" : ObjectId("5c7121b794b7b935e41568b3"),
"pinned" : false,
"warned" : false,
"marked" : false
}
```

the code i have try:

```
 con.collection("message").aggregate([
            {$match: {"chId": chId}},
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "student",
                    localField: "usrId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "student"
                }
            },
            { $unwind: { path: "$student", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "chatAdmin",
                    localField: "usrId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "chAdmin"
                }
            },
            { $unwind: { path: "$chAdmin", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

        ])
```

the result I want is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c73d1aec058ed1b1ce0acb4"),
"msg" : "test",
"usrId" : ObjectId("5c63f0f1dcebbc69fba10db5"),
"chId" : ObjectId("5c7121b794b7b935e41568b3"),
"pinned" : false,
"warned" : false,
"marked" : false,
"user"{ "role":"student" , image :"" , "name":"test"}
}
```

or if the sender is admin :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c73d1aec058ed1b1ce0acb4"),
"msg" : "test",
"usrId" : ObjectId("5c63f0f1dcebbc69fba10db5"),
"chId" : ObjectId("5c7121b794b7b935e41568b3"),
"pinned" : false,
"warned" : false,
"marked" : false,
"user"{ "role":"admin" , image :"" , "name":"test"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider your design. MongoDB is not a relational database, therefore you don't have tables, and you would usually want to avoid joins as a main pattern, especially when you have large data.

It's better if you read about denormalization of NoSQL databases. For example, it's better to have both students and admins in the same collection. And even better not to make joins, but to embed their data or a brief information, that is enough for you in most of the cases, inside the messages collection. It's a duplication, but you earn low latency, and that's what NoSQL databases are all about. Also, you might consider a conventional relational database.

That be said, for the sake of learning, you can do something like this:

```
$addFields: {
    user: {
        $cond: [
            {$ifNull: ['$student', false]},
            {role: 'admin', image: $chAdmin.image, name: $chAdmin.name},
            {role: 'student', image: $student.image, name: $student.name}
        ]
    }
}
```